# Pandas DF referencing the same slice twice in the same computation

Tags: python, pandas

I have a huge data set to process and I am trying to optimize the most costly line, processing wise.

I use a df with 3 columns, A, B and C.
I have 2 values, a and b, which are used to update the value of C in a subset of the df.

Before I continue, let me define a textual substitution to increase readability:

```
filter(_X) -> df.loc[df['A'] < a, _X]
```

Every time I type "filter", please substitute it with the text on the right (applying the correct argument in place of the parameter _X - think C/C++ macros).
The line of code in question is:

```
filter('C') += a * np.minimum(filter('B'), b)
```

What I'm not sure about is if python will process "filter" twice when evaluating the expression, or if it will use a "reference" (a-la C++) and only do it once.
In the former case, is there a way for me to rewrite the expression in a way to avoid the double execution of the code of "filter"?

Moreover, if you have suggestions on how to rewrite the "filter" itself, I'd be happy to test them.

EDIT:
Expanded version of the code:

```
df.loc[df['A'] < a, 'C'] += a * np.minimum(df.loc[df['A'] < a, 'B'], b)
```

Comment: is your textual substitution strictly for Stack Overflow purposes? as someone who only codes in Python the relation to C++ makes me lose my train of thought. This may be the case for others

Comment: Yeah, it was meant to help. I'm editing with an expanded version

Comment: So by your code, are you trying to filter your dataframe where `A` is less than some value `a`, then add the current values of column `C` with the minimum of column `B`? You may want to add a sample dataframe to show exactly what you want to accomplish as well :)

Comment: is `b` an array of some kind? [`np.minimum()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.minimum.html) returns the minimum value between two arrays.

Comment: For future reader reference: no, **b** is a scalar. I perform multiple passes (execution of the line in my post) over the df, each time **b** changes, but within a single pass it is a single, constant, scalar. np.minimum is able to handle the case of df-column vs scalar too.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you may not need to "filter twice" after the `+=`. see my example below:

```
np.random.seed(5)
df =  pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(4, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))


    A   B   C   D
0   99  78  61  16
1   73  8   62  27
2   30  80  7   76
3   15  53  80  27
```

Now if you wanted to add the values of the minimum of columns `C` and `D` to the current value of `B` that would simply be: `df.loc[df['A'] < 80, 'B'] += np.minimum(df['C'], df['D'])`

```
    A    B      C   D
0   99  78.0    61  16  
1   73  35.0    62  27 #<--- meets condition 8+27=35
2   30  87.0    7   76 #<--- meets condition 80+7=87
3   15  80.0    80  27 #<--- meets condition 53+27=80
```

Notice how when `A` < 80. the `B` value changes with whichever value in `C` or `D` is smaller. One thing to note is that `B` turns to a float. Not sure why.

Comment: In my case the minimum is between df['C'] and a single scalar, but this detail does not change the solution. You answer is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I just tested your suggestion against my original code. Apparently it's faster to leave the code the way I initially wrote it, as without the second filter the code is way slower (I had to gave up on the processing after waiting 5 times the time, seeing it was still not done).

Comment: @Dirich, hmmm that's interesting! in my testing my solution tends to be faster. what is your `df.shape`?

Comment: I tested with a dataframe with 11 columns and ~20000 rows if I remember correctly (can't check until monday). Using a smaller dataframe (~5000 columns I think) resulted in a speed down of 1.5.